# Problem mounting mmcblk

Tags: mount, automounting, sd-card

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 on a Vaio laptop.

When I insert my card it is not automatically mounted. I need to remove and insert around 3 or 4 times until the file manager opens.

So I'm trying to mount it after I insert it (because I'm afraid that remove and inserting it could damage it). But I can not mount it using terminal.

I have some questions:

Here is the output of `fdisk -l`

> ```
> Disco /dev/mmcblk0: 7969 MB, 7969177600 bytes
> 221 cabeças, 20 setores/trilhas, 3521 cilindros, total de 15564800 setores
> Unidades = setores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Tamanho do setor (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> Tamanho da E/S (mínimo/ideal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> Identificador do disco: 0x00000000
>
> Dispositivo Boot      Início        Fim      Blocos   Id  Sistema
> /dev/mmcblk0p1            8192    15564799     7778304    b  FAT32 W95
> ```

1. why is it in `/dev/mmcblk0p1` instead of some `sdx`?
2. Since it shows `b  FAT32 W95` should I use `-t vfat` option to `mount`?
3. why `sudo file -s /dev/mmcblk0p1` is returning `/dev/mmcblk0p1: x86 boot sector`? So should I use another `-t` option for file system?

I'm confusing. I just want to be able to mount it with a single line of command on terminal (since the auto mount is not working).

Answer (score 4):

> why is it in /dev/mmcblk0p1 instead of some sdx?

That's caused by udev' rules. 'sdx' - that's a typically udev name for SATA-based devices.

> Since it shows b  FAT32 W95 should I use -t vfat option to mount?

Yes, this is a correct option to use.

> why sudo file -s /dev/mmcblk0p1 is returning /dev/mmcblk0p1: x86 boot sector? So should I use another -t option for file system?

Have you created any kind of filesystem there? Have you ever mounted that correctly and have you ever used it?

In my opinion, the best solution for you:
0) Backup all important data somewhere
1) Completely re-format your card via `mkfs.vfat /dev/mmcblk0p1`
2) Mount it manulally via `mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mount/path` (any path you wish - i.e /mnt/sdcard)

You'll see the content of your card in that directory, where you've just mounted.

Good luck!

Comment: I understood the first 2 answers. For the 3rd, I remember to had formatted it some time ago but I'm not sure if I use the camera (sony) to do it or if I did it using Gparted. Since I use the card for the camera and it contains some sony's folder inside, do you think that is good to format it using linux?

Comment: @Sigur, don't be afraid of investigations! :)

I'd gonna perform the following actions:
1) Format it via linux tools, test its' mountability and readability in your laptop.
2) If everything is OK, insert your card into your camera and test it. If it won't recognize it, it should propose you to re-format your card in camera - perform that action and try to mount it again.

Comment: do you think that `vfat` will work with the Sony camera? I'm making a backup now and format it later. Thanks.

Comment: I can't promise you, but it should. If not - follow my step #2, please.

Comment: I formatted it and now `fdisk -l` says that `/dev/mmcblk0` does not contain a valid partition table. But I can use it with the camera. I tried to create a table using Gparted but it says that there is come label problem.